# Find range for each category in pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
var1    Name    var3
5       1       3           
6       1       3           
7       1       3           
8       2       1           
9       2       4
```

and I'm trying to create a new column (`length`) with the range of `var1` for each `Name`. I'm assuming my code will look something like this:

```
for Name in Names:
    return df['var1'].max-df['var1'].min as df['length']
```

but I'm not quite sure how to turn this into a working function to get the following output:

```
var1    Name    var3 length
5       1       3    2       
6       1       3    2       
7       1       3    2       
8       2       1    1       
9       2       4    1
```

alternatively a count of `var1` would work too

```
var1    Name    var3 length
5       1       3    3       
6       1       3    3       
7       1       3    3       
8       2       1    2       
9       2       4    2
```

Comment: Question not clear. Can you post the expected output dataframe?

Comment: `df.groupby('Name')['var1'].apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())`?

Comment: `df.groupby('Name')['var1'].agg(np.ptp)` or `transform(np.ptp)` if you want the original shape